# Changing the default ISBN of ean13isbn package

Tags: barcodes

I am kindly requesting for assistance on how to change the default ISBN when using the `ean13isbn` package. If I change the numbers on 978-80-85955-35-4 I get an error. Let's say I want to change 978-80-85955-35-4 to 026-37-74794-59-8, is it possible? Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-4,SC0]{ean13isbn}
\begin{document}
    \EANisbn[SC3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This exact MWE works as expected for me, with ean13isbn cersion 2021-01-24 and pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019). What exactly is the issue in your case?

Comment: What did the error say?  Let me guess that it complained that the check sum digit was wrong...

Comment: The last digit of an ISBN is a check sum digit.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN#ISBN-13_check_digit_calculation

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: 026-37-74794-59-8 is not a valid ISBN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print any valid ISBN-13, not just the one specified in the package options.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[SC3]{ean13isbn}

\AddToHook{cmd/EANbox/before}{\leavevmode}

\begin{document}

Start a paragraph

\EANisbn[ISBN=978-020-1558-02-9] is not flush left, but aligned with the indentation above

\begin{center}
\EANisbn[ISBN=978-020-113448-3]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]