Generating ISBN Barcodes
Consider the following code which I compile with xelatex:
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{9780895558213}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}

which produces the output:

QUESTION: How may I add atop the displayed image, the associated 10-digit ISBN (0-89555-821-1) as follows: ISBN 0-89555-821-1?
Thank you.

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656057/4427 help?

@egreg Is there a way to do it using the above invoked package pst-barcode?

Use a tabular:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{phv}\small ISBN\hfill 0-89555-821-1\\
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
\psbarcode{9780895558213}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


I'm not sure I'd mix ean13 with ean10.

Use the isbn encoder which is intended for generating ISBN numbers:
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}

This produces the following symbol:

Notice that the encoder has converted your legacy 10-digit ISBN number into the equivalent 13-digit modern format that is required at Point of Sale. If you would like to avoid this conversion then you can supply the legacy option, however use of the legacy format is not recommended.
Additional information about the 10-digit to 13-digit ISBN conversion process, as well as the relationship of ISBN to EAN-13, can be found here.

@DDS I've expanded the answer with a link to additional information that you might find relevant.

Thank you again for this helpful answer. Offhand, would you know how to darken the ISBN? I have asked a question to this effect here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730463/how-to-darken-the-isbn-in-a-pst-barcode
